# How to validate file input using Parsley JS?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I've used a custom validator to validate the file extension of a file input below.

```
.addValidator('filetype', function(value, requirement) {
    return value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() === requirement;
})
```

I'd really like to get access to the actual file so I can check the MIME type. Is there a way to get a reference back to the input so I can check the actual file date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the third argument is the parsley instance.

See [this issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/989) and [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/02vjbLrs/14/)

PRs for better documentation, as well as clean file validators in `extra/` welcome.